# Prove that the multiplicative inverse of r∈S is in S

Tags: elementary-number-theory

this is a question related to the proof of Euler's theorem, let m be a prime, S be the set of numbers that are relatively prime with m, how can we show that for any r∈S, there exists a multiplicative inverse mod m that is in the set S.

Comment: with the extended euclidean algorithm (EEA).

Comment: Use Bézout's identity for $r$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT.** Given two integers $A,B$, we can find $x,y$ so that $Ax+By= D$, where $D$ is the gcd of $A,B$. So take $A$ to be a integer non-multiple of $p$ and $B=p$. What must $D$ be? Then what can you say about this equation mod $p$? How does this show what you want?

Comment: yes, I see that D must be 1, however, I'm struggling with the multiplicative inverse must be in set S

Comment: @Charlie If it weren't what would $Ax$ be mod $p$? Then....

Answer (score 0):

$r$ and $m$ are relatively prime is equivalent to $\exists x,y$ such that $rx+my=1$.  Notice this last equation says $x\cong r^{-1}\bmod m$.  So we get that $r^{-1}$ and $m$ are relatively prime, by the same equation.

Answer (score 0):

If $r$ is relatively prime to $m$ then so is any power of $r$.  Since $S$ is finite, you must have $r^a \equiv r^b \pmod{m}$ for some $a < b$ by pigeon-hole principle.  Since $r^a$ is relatively prime to $m$, you can divide through by it to get $1 \equiv r^{b-a} \pmod{m}.$   Therefore $r^{b-a-1}$ is an inverse for $r$ and relatively prime to $m$.